# ingress-nginx No IP Address

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I've created a test k8s cluster using [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray) (3 nodes, virtualbox 
 centos vm based) and have been trying to follow the [guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/deploy/index.md) for setting up nginx ingress, but i never seem to get an external address assigned to my service:

I can see that the ingress controller is apparently installed:

```
[root@k8s-01 ~]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -l app=ingress-nginx
NAMESPACE       NAME                                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx   nginx-ingress-controller-58c9df5856-v6hml   1/1       Running   0          28m
```

And following the [prerequisites](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/PREREQUISITES/) docs, i have set up the http-svc sample service:

```
[root@k8s-01 ~]# kubectl get po
NAME                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
http-svc-794dc89f5-f2vlx   1/1       Running   0          27m

[root@k8s-01 ~]# kubectl get svc http-svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
http-svc     LoadBalancer   10.233.25.131   <pending>     80:30055/TCP   27m

[root@k8s-01 ~]# kubectl describe svc http-svc
Name:                     http-svc
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=http-svc
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=http-svc
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.233.25.131
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30055/TCP
Endpoints:                10.233.65.5:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                -------
  Normal  Type    27m   service-controller  ClusterIP -> LoadBalancer
```

As far as i know, i should see a `LoadBalancer Ingress` entry, but the External IP for the service still appears to be pending, so something isn't working, but i'm at a loss where to diagnose what has gone wrong

Comment: External load balancer depends on the environment you are running in. For cloud providers, this is automagically configured; for custom installation it is not. Do you have a LB in your environment?

Comment: No, I've probably misunderstood, but i want to access a service on a well known port, and i thought NodePort always gives you a random port, so an ingress controller allows you to map from say port 443 on each node to the service port?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating your cluster locally, exposing your service as type `LoadBalancer` will not provision a loadbalancer for you. Use the type `LoadBalancer` if you are creating your cluster in a cloud environment such as AWS or GKE. In AWS it will auto-provision you an loadbalancer (ELB) and assign an external ip for the service.

To make your service work with current settings and environment change your service type from `Loadbalancer` to `NodePort`.

Comment: And if i want to access that service in a well known port? Doesn't NodePort give you a random port? How can i get say 443 for a service with an ingress controller?

Comment: Yes it's totally doable. NodePort will give you a random port if you don't specify a static NodePort by yourself. You can specify static NodePort within the range `30000-32767` in your service under `ports` section as follows :                                                                                                              
     `port: 443
      nodePort: 30443
      name: https`

Comment: Can you bind to 443 vs something that's going to need advertising to consumers?

Comment: Yes of course. In the above example all the traffic hit on port 30443 will routed to port 443

Comment: This may be helpful for you. http://blog.oestrich.org/2016/01/nodeport-kubernetes-load-balancer/. If you want to 443 the external port it is pretty obvious that you have to setup SSL for your service.